# How to use regex expression to check phone number with validation provider and v-slot

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, validation, vue-component

I am trying to add the code for phone field validation in vue.js
I am trying to check the user phone number with my regex expression and also field will not be empty.

```
<div v-if="shouldPhoneFieldDisplay" class="flex xs12 sm5">
    <validation-provider v-slot="{ errors }" rules="{ required:true, regex: /^\(?\d{3}\)?[-\s]?\d{3}[-\s]?\d{4}$/ }">
        <label for="bill-to-phone">Phone Number</label>
        <input name="Phone Number" v-model="data.bill.billphone" class="form-control" id="billphone" type="tel" maxlength = "255">
        <span class="error--text">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
    </validation-provider>
</div>
```

But this is not working, this shows the error on the browser.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: No such validator '{ required, helpers.regex( /^(?d{3})?[-s]?d{3}[-s]?d{4}$/ ) }' exists.
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please edit your question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see this failure ourselves in action (instead of just screenshots). More info and tips can be found at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically the "Help others reproduce the problem" section.

Comment: This is a warning. Validating phone numbers is not as simple as it appears.Your validation does not allow for extensions or for international numbers. It really only applies to US, Canada and NANP countries.  Given the flexibility you already have in your regex you could just drop it entirely in favor of only allowing characters like [0-9+\-x\\(\\)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using VeeValidator you can declare rules in two ways, as a string list with items seperated by a pipe character:

```
<validation-rule rules="required|telephone">
</validation-rule>
```

But it's also possible to provide an object:

```
<validation-rule v-bind:rules="{ required: true, regex: /.+/ }">
</validation-rule>
```

In your case you forgot to add v-bind or `:` to rules, now VeeValidator interprets your rules as a string and complains that it cannot find the rule `{ require: true, ... }`. So the solution would be to add `v-bind:` or `:` to rules, like in the previous example.

More info can be found here:

- https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/basics.html#adding-rules
- https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/rules.html#rules